# Gcm : Impact if I use Ip 0.0.0.0/0 forever?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I follow this link http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html to make app with gcm and successfully sending data, I use the ip 0.0.0.0/0 to get api key, but in docs written this ip just for testing purpose

```
In the resulting configuration dialog, supply your server's IP address. For testing purposes, you can use 0.0.0.0/0.
```

what impact it had on the app if I keep using Ip 0.0.0.0/0 forever?
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0/0` means you do not care about the address that access your site; which in other words, letting everyone use your API Key and your quota.

Comment: when I insert 0.0.0.0/0 I get the private key, whether it's private key for everyone? I also ever use my server ip but I often get an error "Curl failed: Could not resolve host 'android.googleapis.com",so I decided to use the ip 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I guess as long as you don't mind someone might steal your key and use your quota, you can do it forever:) I mean people look at packets that got send over the network and do things :)